# Magento 2.2.5 : Module manager is not working in admin panel

Tags: web-setup-wizard, magento-2.2.5

I upgrade to Magento 2.2.2 to 2.2.5.

Now, in my admin panel When I open Module Manager, Then it was display error in console and grid not display.

Error :

> GET : https://www.example.com/mage2.2.5/setup/index.php/moduleGrid/modules 500(Internal Server Error) angular.js : 7715

How, can I remove this error and display grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to on this below path :

> setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Grid/Module.php

Go to line 181 and replace this below code :

```
$item['moduleName'] = isset($item['moduleName']) ? $item['moduleName'] : $this->packageInfo->getModuleName($item['name']);
```

Clean cache and then refresh module manager page.